# Where does this given info come from?

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

I am following this [slide](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse421/10au/lectures/05fft.pdf) on FFT.  On the last page, it says:

[image: img]

I would like to ask where $a = A(2)$ comes from.  Thanks.

Comment: That's the definition of the binary expansion.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base two, a number $b = b_{n-1}\dots b_0$ stands for $b = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i 2^i$.

Defining the polynomial $B(X) =\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i X^i$, you have $b = B(2)$.

Note : in base $\beta$, the number $b = b_{n-1}\dots b_0$  is $B(\beta)$.

Comment: Thanks!!!  This clarifies everything.  I was wondering what happens if I swap $2$ with something else.